# When does $k \mid n^m + m^n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

> Determine all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there exists an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}: \textrm{gcd}(k, n) = 1$ so that $$k \mid n^m + m^n$$

I don't know the origin of this problem. I'll share what I've been able to deduce.

**1. $k$ is not odd.**

Suppose $k$ is odd. Let $p$ be the smallest prime such that $p \mid k$ and take $n = (p - 1)^2$. This is valid as $p - 1$ is smaller than every prime dividing $k$, so $k$ and $n$ are coprime. Now,

$$n^m + m^n \equiv (p - 1)^{2m} + m^{(p - 1)^2} \equiv 2 \pmod{p}$$

for all $m$ such that $p \nmid m$ (this follows by Fermat's Little Theorem). It's also very straightforward to check that $p \nmid n^m + m^n$ in the case that $p \mid m$. Therefore, $k$ cannot be odd.

**2. $k = 2p$ for prime $p$ always works.**

Take $k = 2p$ for an odd prime $p$. Now, for any $n$ such that $p \nmid n$, the number $m = (p - 1)(p + 2n) + n$ satisfies the condition.

$$n^m + m^n \equiv n^n + (-n)^n \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

This follows from Fermat's Little Theorem and the fact that $n$ is odd. As $(p - 1)(p + 2n) + n$ is odd, we also have $2 \mid n^m + m^n$.

**3. $k = 2p^a$ works for every $a \in \mathbb{N}$.**

Proceed by induction. Take $a = 1$ for the base. We have already proven this above. For the inductive step, note that

$$\varphi(p^{a + 1}) = p^a(p - 1)$$

where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. Fix $n$ and let $m_0$ be the number such that $2p^a \mid n^m_0 + m_0^n$, which exists by hypothesis. Consider the number $m = m_0 + p^a(p - 1)l$, where $l$ is to be determined later. We have by Euler's Theorem:

$$n^m + m^n \equiv n^{m_0 + p^a(p - 1)} + (m_0 + p^a(p - 1))^n) \equiv n^{m_0} + (m_0 - p^a)^n \equiv n^{m_0} + \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i} m_0^{n - i} (p^a)^i \pmod{p^{a + 1}}$$

Here, every term of $\sum_{i = 0}^n m_0^i (p^a)^i$ except the first two is divisible by $p^{a + 1}$, so

$$n^m + m^n \equiv n^{m_0} + m_0^n + nlm_0^{n - 1} p^a \pmod{p^{a + 1}}$$

$m_0^n + n^{m_0}$ is divisible by $p^a$ by assumption, so write $m_0^n + n^{m_0} = p^ab$ for some $b$. Now,

$$n^m + m^n \equiv p^a(b + (nm_0^{n - 1})l) \pmod{p^{a + 1}}$$

Here, $n$ is coprime to $p$ by assumption and $m_0$ (and, therefore, $m_0^{n - 1}$) by construction. Therefore, we may choose $l$ such that $p \mid b + (nm_0^{n - 1})l$. As the value is also pretty clearly divisible by $2$, this completes the proof.

**4. $k = 2^a$ works for every $a \in \mathbb{N}$**

The cases $a = 1$ and $a = 2$ can be checked by hand and the rest can be proven by induction in a similar, but simpler manner to the third claim.

It seems, now, that the answer should be: "all even numbers". Perhaps we may prove that the condition is "multiplicative" in a way. This is what I've been trying to do, but unsuccessfully. Please share any insights. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24k%5Cmid%20n%5Em%2Bm%5En%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cgcd(k%2Cn)%3D1%24&p=1), I found the AoPS thread [artistic number](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2474161p20729740), with it linking to [Artistic Numbers - CMC 10B #22 & CMC 12B #19](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2474161p20729740). I also the found the related [Exponential Number theory](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1380528p7651194).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Okay, you really scared me there before I realized that $m$ in the linked problem has to be constant with respect to $n$. It's entirely possible that someone made a typo while copying this problem from somewhere, leaving me to find a much tougher version online.